# Modifying an observable's stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I made a directive and service to sort my table columns as follows:

my sort service:

```
onSort({ column, direction }: SortEvent, observable: Observable<any[]>, headers: QueryList<SortableHeaderDirective>) {
    // resetting other headers
    headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.sortable !== column) {
        header.direction = '';
      }
    });

    if (direction === '') {
      //Do nothing
    } else {
      observable
        .pipe(
          tap(results => {
            return results.sort((a, b) => (direction === 'asc' ?
              compareString(a[column], b[column]) :
              -compareString(a[column], b[column])))
          })
        ).subscribe();
    }
  }
```

The issue is this used to work perfectly fine until I recently updated all my packages (angular 9, latest rxjs etc) - It still works when i debug through it but it does not update the observable on the template (the place calling this service function). my linter says the .subscribe() is deprecated, but I haven't been able to figure out how to modify my existing function to make use of the newest observable callbacks. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you show how you call `onSort`?

Answer (score 0):

A [rxjs map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) is better candidate to transform the whole object array.

Take a look at the example

```js
function compareString(prev, next) {
  return prev > next ? 1 : -1
}

function resetHeaders(column, headers) {
  return headers.map(header => ({
    ...header,
    direction: header.sortable !== column ? '' : header.direction
  }));
}

const sort = (column, direction) => {

  let compareFunction = (prev, next) => -compareString(prev[column], next[column]);
  
  if (direction === 'asc') {
    compareFunction = (prev, next) => compareString(prev[column], next[column]);
  }

  return (results) => {

    const sorted = [...results];
    sorted.sort(compareFunction)
    return sorted;

  }
}

function onSort({
  column,
  direction
}, observable, headers) {

  headers = resetHeaders(column, headers);

  if (direction === '') {
    return;
  }

  const sorter = sort(column, direction);

  observable
    .pipe(
      rxjs.operators.map(sorter)
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
}

const headers = [{
    direction: '',
    sortable: ''
  },
  {
    direction: '',
    sortable: ''
  }
]

const observable = rxjs.of([{
    name: 'A',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    value: 2
  }
])

const sortData = {
  column: 'name',
  direction: 'asc'
}

onSort(sortData, observable, headers)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```